# Where does the MSCO Polaris actually go, and how do I travel with it?

Tags: routes, russia, ferries, arctic

The [Murmansk shipping company](http://en.msco.ru/) operates [two passenger ships](http://en.fleet.msco.ru/). The [Klavdiya Elanskaya](http://en.fleet.msco.ru/passenger/klavdiya-elanskaya/) travels between [Murmansk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmansk) and [Ostrovnoy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrovnoy,_Murmansk_Oblast). Considering that Ostrovnoy is a [closed city](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city), this is probably not an accessible tourist destination (although it also appears to serve [Chapoma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapoma) and [Arkhangelsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkhangelsk)). Considerably more spectacular appears the route of the [Polaris](http://en.fleet.msco.ru/passenger/polaris/), which supposedly serves Murmansk, the [Solovetsky islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovetsky_Islands), [Franz-Josef Land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Josef_Land), [Spitsbergen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitsbergen), [Greenland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenland) and [Iceland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland). This sounds rather unlikely and I really wonder if it's true.

[image: Route of the MSCO Polaris?] 
<sup>Route of the MSCO Polaris? Source: [MSCO Polaris](http://en.fleet.msco.ru/passenger/polaris/)</sup>

What is the nature of the MSCO Polaris? Is this a passenger ship that ordinary travellers can book travel with? Is it a regular ship with a timetable? Some kind of cruise-ship? Or is this map just a proud display of "look where we've been"?

Comment: I think I'll find something, but only tomorrow.

Comment: Knowing Russian might help (:

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck now. Officials are not answering, and no info about schedule even in Russian version. I think currently this ship is out of sea. Still investigating.

Answer (score 4):

While this may be out of date but there is bad news:

[Polaris is moving to Sakhalin](http://www.b-port.com/news/item/113825.html), so whatever routes it used to run are no longer being serviced by MSCO

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this boat appears to take passengers, and seems quite luxurious!

Have a look at this page for information and details on how to book: http://en.fleet.msco.ru/passenger/polaris/#2

[image]

Comment: The question already included this link, so this adds no information.

Comment: Exactly. The information is all there.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm looking for *more* information, such as *Is this a passenger ship that ordinary travellers can book travel with? Is it a regular ship with a timetable? Some kind of cruise-ship? Or is this map just a proud display of "look where we've been"?*...

Comment: The ship is a cruise ship for passengers, yes. And there are various photos online taken from/of it on various cruises, but it seems that since about July last year it has not been active, unlike its sister ship. Haven't been able to find out whether it is just undergoing maintenance.